# Create a CSV file from another CSV file by removing some columns in PERL

Tags: perl, csv

Hi I am trying to read a csv file  say `first.csv` and select some columns in it and write those columns to a new csv file `new.csv` . 
Here is my code :-

```
 my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

    open (my $fh , "first.csv") or die "cannot open $file\n";
    open (my $mh , "new.csv") or die "cannot open file $!\n";
    while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)){

      my $id = $row->[0]; 
      my $words = $row->[2];
      my $bits = $row->[3];

    }
    close $fh;
```

And after this I have no clue how to write only these `$id,$words,$bits` to  `new.csv` .
Can anyone please help me do it .

Comment: I have no idea about perl, but a CSV file has commas between subsequent columns. So, you could probably just write $id + "," + $words + "," + $bits + "\n" and be done with it.

Comment: CSV is such a simple format: just print it: `print qq{"$id","$words","$bits"\n};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do: (untested)

```
$csv->print($mh, [$id, $words, $bits]);
```

From the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV) documentation:

```
$status = $csv->print ($io, $colref); # Write an array of fields
                                      # immediately to a file $io
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -MText::CSV -e'my $csv = Text::CSV->new();while(my $row = $csv->getline(ARGV)){$csv->print(STDOUT, [@$row[0,2,3]])}' first.csv > new.csv
```